# Flowplayer Clip not scaling

Tags: video, scaling, flowplayer

I think the issue is that flowplayer isn't recognising the additional  that has the properties I want to apply to the player. But I've tried a ton of combinations and can't seem to make it work

```
   /* custom player skin */
    .flowplayer { width: 100%; background-color: #000;}
    .flowplayer .fp-controls { display:none;}
    .flowplayer .fp-timeline { display:none;}
    .flowplayer .fp-progress { display:none;}
    .flowplayer .fp-buffer { display:none;}

    </style>

    <!-- flowplayer depends on jQuery 1.7.1+ -->
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <!-- flowplayer javascript component -->
    <script src="http://releases.flowplayer.org/5.3.2/flowplayer.min.js"></script>

 </head>

 <body>
    <div data-swf="http://releases.flowplayer.org/5.3.2/flowplayer.swf"
      class="flowplayer fixed-controls no-toggle no-time no-volume no-mute"
      data-ratio="0.416" data-embed="false" data-fullscreen="false" data-scaling="scale" data-keyboard="false">
      <script>
             flowplayer("player", "flowplayer.swf", {
        clip:  {
            autoPlay: true,
          autoBuffering: true
          scaling: scale
         }
         });
     </script>
        <video loop="loop">

         <source type="video/mp4" src="whitenoise.mp4"/>

         </video>

       </div>

     </body>
```

Answer (score 2):

According to this doc
http://flash.flowplayer.org/documentation/configuration/clips.html
scaling parameter is String. So you should use with quotation marks.

```
scaling: 'scale'
```

And also 'scale' is default value, so you do not have to write. If you want to see how this parameter make difference, use 16:9 video with

```
scaling: 'fit'
```